# find control id by jquery and pass it to function to toggle it

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net, css

find control id by jquery and pass it to function to  toggle it.

```js
function toggleDiv() {
   var $usr = $this.find('[id*=shoow]');
   $($usr).toggle('slow');
}
```

```html
<asp:LinkButton  runat="server" OnClientClick="toggleDiv(); return false;">Detials</asp:LinkButton>

  <table>
    <tr>
      <td id="shoow" style="width:650px;height:100px;background-color:blue; display:none;">
      </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: What is your actual question? Is there an error? Provide a bit more information on your problem.

Comment: i want to give id from code behind or jqueryfunction to toggle function

Comment: You want your `toggleDiv` function to accept the id of the element as a parameter?

Answer (score 0):

Initially, since you have declared a server side control, `LinkButton`, you have to provide an `ID`, for it.

```
<asp:LinkButton  ID="linkButtonId" runat="server">Details</asp:LinkButton>
```

You don't have to use the `find` function for this purpose. Actually, we use this function for the following reason:

> Get the descendants of each element in the current set of matched
>   elements, filtered by a selector, jQuery object, or element.

**What you could do?**

I suggest at the bottom of your page before the body's closing tag to add this script

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function(){
        $("#"+<%=linkButtonId.ClientID%>).click(function(){
            $('#shoow').toggle('slow');
        });
    })
</script>
```

**Important Note**

*You should load the jQuery before this script.*

> i want to give id from code behind by find control function or jquery
>   funtion becuase i have datalist generat id's random.

```
You could select then the element like below:

$("[id*="+"shoow"+"]").toggle('slow');
```

Try the following snippet to see what I mean:

```js
$(function(){
    $("#buttonId").click(function(){
        $("[id*="+"shoow"+"]").toggle('slow');
    })
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="buttonId">Details</button>

<table>
      <tr>
     <td id="3shoow2" style="width:650px;height:100px;background-color:blue; display:none;">

        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: ok i want to give id from code behind or jqueryfunction to toggle function

Comment: i want to give id from code behind by find control function or jquery funtion becuase i have datalist generat id's random.

Comment: @boshkash check the new update and please let me know.

Answer (score 0):

I agree the answer of Christos.

Yes you don't have to use **`find`** function

Instead please use jQuery:

```
$('#shoow').toggle('slow');
```